# Correct Terminology in the Context of Rings

Tags: ring-theory, terminology, translation-request, mathematical-spanish

Suppose I have a ring $(A, ◦, •)$ where $A$ is a set of elements $\{α, β, γ,\ldots\}$.

Can $◦$ and $•$ with which the ring is equipped be properly termed, in English, its "internal laws of composition," or is "internal binary operators" better in this context?

Are $A$, $◦$, and $•$ taken together—when written as $(A, ◦, •)$, e.g.—properly termed a ternary, triad, or triplet, in English?

I am trying to translate the Spanish:

> Se denomina *anillo* a una terna $(A, ◦, •)$, donde $A$ es un conjunto de
>   elementos $\{α, β, γ, …\}$, dotado de dos leyes de composición internas, $◦$ y $•$, …

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would translate it as:

"A ring is a triplet $(A, \circ, \bullet)$, where $A$ is the set $\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \ldots, \}$ with two binary operations $\circ$ and $\bullet$".

This is not a literal translation, but the literal translation would be a bit awkward in my opinion.

As is clear now, I choose to translate 'internal laws of composition' as 'binary operations'.

'Internal binary operations' is uncommon and redundant since the definition of [binary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation#Terminology) entails that it is 'internal'.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that the literal translation is an older way of saying "binary operation". Why "triplet" and not "triad"? And why not "internal binary operation" instead of just "binary operation"? thanks

Comment: Simply because it is more common (I think), I've never seen *triad*. As for the second question, my answer already answers it: it's redudant and uncommon. I also have never seen it.

Comment: How is it redundant? See [this](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_binaria#Clase_de_operaci.C3.B3n_binaria). The quote I gave is _introducing_ rings, not assuming the reader knows anything about them.

Comment: Also, isn't "operator" slightly better than "operation"?

Comment: @Geremia I misunderstood the concept of 'internal', but I mantain my translation. If one wants to be very careful, one could add "with two binary operations $\circ$ and $\bullet$ defined on $A$" and by definition of binary operation, they are internal operations. I should also add that I've never seen these concepts of internal and external operations in english.

Comment: Just for the record: the expression "internal composition law" is currently used in french: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_de_composition_interne and until now I was thinking it was the same in english... We, frenchies, loves all those baroque embellishments :p !

Comment: @Geremia *Operation* is an established term. *Operator* is too, but with a different meaning, *operator* usually is a function that takes functions as inputs.

Comment: @Sebastien: Is that the same as saying it's closed?

Comment: Also, it seems ["external binary operation" is proper English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation#External_binary_operations), but for some reason not "internal binary operation"?

Comment: @Geremia Seems so, but you're only interested in internal binary operations and in this case *binary operation* is much more common.

Comment: It's hard because saying "defined on $A$" is only half of what "internal" means… I suppose I could say it's "defined on $A$" and closed? Ah, but it's so much easier to just say "internal"…

Comment: @Geremia No, being closed means that the outputs are elements of $A$. I want to take back what I said about them being defined on $A$, they are actually defined on $A^2$. What I meant to say was:  "with two binary operations $∘$ and $∙$ on A". There is no risk of confusion because of the definition of binary operation.

Comment: @Geremia: if "closed" means "the output is in A" then yes, "interne" in "loi de composition interne" holds for "closed". More precesily, a "loi de composition interne" on a set $E$ is simply an application $E\times E \to E$. That's it (which is the same as "binary operation" in english). Damn! Vocabulary in english is far more intuitive than in french !

Comment: @Geremia Do you still require help with this?

Comment: @GitGud: No, but thanks for reminding me to mark your answer as the answer. ☺

Comment: @Geremia Thank you for the '$\huge ☺$' thing.

Comment: @GitGud: You're welcome. It's UTF-16 0x263A. There's a frowning one, too: $\huge{☹}$ (0x2639), a postal mark one: $\huge{〠}$ (0x3020), and a black smiling one: $\huge{☻}$ (0x263B).